# Can't verify contract on Etherscan

Tags: etherscan

I'm trying to verify a contract on the Rinkeby version of etherscan. My contract has couple of dependencies like:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/presets/ERC20PresetMinterPauser.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
```

I can see there's an option on etherscan to add external libraries:

[image]

But I don't know how to find the address of those `openzeppelin` contracts, where can I find them?

Comment: those contracts are not "libraries", you don't have to give anything here. The easiest way is to use remix ide or hardhat plugin

Comment: Besides the suggestions made by @MajdTL, also see my tool [multisol](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol).